# How can I select elements having specific siblings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

How can I prevent anchor (`<a>`) tag from doing nothing if `li` has `ul` according to the following code:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
 <div id="leftside-navigation" class="nano">
  <ul class="nano-content">
   <li>
    <a href="index.html">
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="sub-menu">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);"> 
       <span>Categories</span>
       <i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
     </a>
     <ul>
       <li>
         <a href="index.html">
           <span>Home</span>
         </a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="index.html">
           <span>Lifestyles</span>
         </a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="index.html">
           <span>Technology</span>
         </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried to put `javascript:void(0)` - it works but I wanted to make it with if else statement or any other way.

I wanted to do that is:

- if `li.submenu` has `ul` `li.has-submenu` `a` prevent default

Comment: I suggest simply not using an anchor and use a `span`.  Change your menu css/js to handle `span` for the sub-menu along with `a`

Comment: I agree with freedomn-m. It's an accessibility and semantics faux pas to use anchors where they don't act as such (or any element, really).

Comment: Your question isn't about stopping anchor behavior. It's about selecting particular anchors. You should revise to clarify that.

Comment: it will be dificult when i went to convert that into wordpress.thats why u know.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a selector for `a` that's a child of an `li` that has a submenu.

```
$("li:has(ul) > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: is this selecting only first anchor tag of li? i mean li.sub-menu>a?

Comment: It selects all the anchors that are direct children of `li`, but not the ones nested more deeply.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to not include the `<a>` tag in general. Just write the the text "Categories" within the `<li class="sub-menu>` and it will display in menu as normal. 
Example:

```
<li class="sub-menu">
       <span>Categories</span>
       <i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
     <ul>
       <li>......
```

Although you would need to add CSS if you want the cursor to change or if you want the text to be underlined for your `<span>` etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
$("li").find("ul > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```